# GridView inconsistancies

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview, android-listview

I have a strange problem - I am using an activity with a ViewSwitcher, this ViewSwitcher has a `ListView` and a `GridView` which use the same `ArrayAdapter{SomeContent}`.

I have made the Adapters so that I can pass them the `R.layout.value` that they use to inflate - this is how I manage consistency across ListView / GridView since I want somewhat different views in these two forms.

And all of this works somewhat perfectly, just not for the first time.

No, for the first time that I run my application in GRID display mode, my gridview tries to use the wrong XML, and ends up trying to use (recycle?) the ListView's XML. I know so because GridView's XML has no reference of checkboxes and I see them constantly.

But when I leave this screen (not even going to say 'activity') and come back to it, everything is inflated perfectly. List always works off the bat, GridViews ~80% don't work only first time.

Any ideas?

Here is some code to get you started.
ADAPTER:

```
public class AudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MusicContent>
{
private Context context;

private ImageView albumArt;
private TextView songName;
private TextView artistName;
private TextView albumName;
private TextView genre;
private TextView duration;
private int viewToUse;

private CheckBox checkbox;
private OnItemClickListener clickListener;
private OnItemSelectedListener focusListener;

private List<MusicContent> content = new ArrayList<MusicContent>();


public AudioAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MusicContent> objects,
        OnItemClickListener clickListener, OnItemSelectedListener focusListener)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.content = objects;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    this.focusListener = focusListener;
    this.viewToUse = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    /**
     * Removed following optimization on purpose due to dynamically using
     * different layouts which may result in wrong view being recycled for
     * use
     */
    //removing it fixed nothing really
    if (row == null)
    {
        // ROW INFLATION
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(viewToUse, parent, false);
    }
    // initiate helpers for onClick hack
    final AdapterView fParent = (AdapterView) parent;
    final View fView = row;
    final int fInt = position;
    final long fLong = row.getId();

    // Get item
    MusicContent item = getItem(position);
    if (item == null)
        return row;

    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_layout);

    // perform a series of checks to maintain customizability
    albumArt = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_image);
    if (albumArt != null)
    {
        if (item.hasAlbumArt()) {
            albumArt.setImageBitmap(item.getAlbumBitmap(context));
        }
        else
            albumArt.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_music_album));
    }

    LinearLayout checkLL = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_music_info);
    if (checkLL != null)
    {
        // display some song info
        songName = (TextView) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_title);
        if (songName != null)
        {
            songName.setText(item.getDisplayName());
            songName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // attach artificial OnItemClick and OnItemSelected listeners
        if (clickListener != null)
        {
            OnClickListener cross = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("SHARK", "internal onClick from adapter!!" + fView);
                    clickListener.onItemClick(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                }
            };
            checkLL.setOnClickListener(cross);
        }
        if (focusListener != null)
        {
            OnFocusChangeListener cross = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus)
                        focusListener.onItemSelected(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                }
            };
            checkLL.setOnFocusChangeListener(cross);
        }

        checkLL = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_artist_info);
        if (checkLL != null)
        {
            // display artist info too
            artistName = (TextView) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_artist_name);
            if (artistName != null)
                artistName.setText(item.getArtist());

            albumName = (TextView) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_album);
            if (albumName != null)
                albumName.setText(item.getAlbum());

            duration = (TextView) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_duration);
            if (duration != null)
                duration.setText(item.getDurationString());

            genre = (TextView) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_genre);
            if (genre != null)
                genre.setText(item.getGenre());

            // block focus on descendants
            checkLL.setDescendantFocusability(RelativeLayout.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

            // attach artificial listeners
            if (clickListener != null)
            {
                OnClickListener cross = new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("SHARK", "internal onClick from adapter!!" + fView);
                        clickListener.onItemClick(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                    }
                };
                checkLL.setOnClickListener(cross);
            }
            if (focusListener != null)
            {
                OnFocusChangeListener cross = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus)
                            focusListener.onItemSelected(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                    }
                };
                checkLL.setOnFocusChangeListener(cross);
            }
        }

        // FrameLayout checkFL = (FrameLayout)
        // row.findViewById(R.id.endoflineinfo);
        checkLL = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.endoflineinfo);
        if (checkLL != null)
        {
            checkbox = (CheckBox) checkLL.findViewById(R.id.in_playlist);
            if (checkbox != null)
            {
                checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (item.getPlaylist() != null)
                    checkbox.setChecked(!item.getPlaylist().isEmpty());
            }
            checkLL.setDescendantFocusability(RelativeLayout.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            if (clickListener != null)
            {
                OnClickListener cross = new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("SHARK", "internal onClick from adapter!!" + fView);
                        clickListener.onItemClick(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                    }
                };
                checkLL.setOnClickListener(cross);
            }
            if (focusListener != null)
            {
                OnFocusChangeListener cross = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus)
                            focusListener.onItemSelected(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
                    }
                };
                checkLL.setOnFocusChangeListener(cross);
            }
        }
    }

    // magic happens where we bind an OnItemClick call to OnClick
    root.setDescendantFocusability(RelativeLayout.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    if (clickListener != null)
    {
        OnClickListener cross = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("SHARK", "internal onClick from adapter!!");
                clickListener.onItemClick(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
            }
        };
        // assign this listener
        root.setOnClickListener(cross);
    }
    if (focusListener != null)
    {
        OnFocusChangeListener cross = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    focusListener.onItemSelected(fParent, fView, fInt, fLong);
            }
        };
        root.setOnFocusChangeListener(cross);
    }

    return row;
}
```

As for why so many ifs and checks - it has to be able to survive different underlying XMLs with missing elements (customizability) and don't worry too much about the onClick / onFocus hacks - they're much needed workarounds....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into how my views are recycled, I came to a conclusion that I was running the app in a different viewmode than it was last left in - this caused GRID views to be saved up and used in LIST, or vice-versa.

After revising, I made sure to restart the app in the same mode that it was previously used or force the new views upon restart be recreating the adapter and reassigning it to my view.